# What is causing these seemingly inconsistent query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare, match, record

I have a problem that's really confounding me.  I half-expect one of you to point out some really dumb mistake that I'm overlooking but I'm really just not seeing it.

I have a table that our production processes have been feeding for something like a year and we just got some crazy tables from our client against which we are trying to match data.  In the following queries, `tableA` is my table and `tableB` is the table we've just imported.

The basic problem is that

```
select *
from tableA
where convert(nvarchar(30),accountNum) not in (
        select CisAC
        from tableB
    )
```

isn't returning any records when I believe it should be.  I think that it should find any records in tableA where the accountNum matches the CisAC field in tableB.  Right?  CisAC is an nvarchar(30) and our accountNum field is a bigint.

To point out why I think an empty return set is wrong:

```
select * from tableA where convert(nvarchar(30),accountNum) = '336906210032'
```

returns one record but

```
select * from tableB where CisAC = '336906210032'
```

does not.

So, what gives?  (And thanks for your time!)

Comment: How about trimming CisAC in Table B to remove leading and trailing whitespace?

Comment: Good idea, but no whitespace.  I also checked for fields where the len(CisAC) was different from 1/2 the DataLength(CisAC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the classic `not in` mistake.  If table B contains any `null` value,

```
where convert(nvarchar(30),accountNum) not in (
        select CisAC
        from tableB
    )
```

will never succeed.  You can write it out like:

```
where convert(nvarchar(30),accountNum) <> null and convert(nvarchar(30),accountNum) <> ...
```

Since any comparison to `null` evaluates to `unknown`, this condition is never true.

Replacing the query with a `join` like the podiluska's answer suggests should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

My suspicion would be null values in tableB causing the `IN` to fail

I would try

```
select * 
from tableA 
     left join tableB
     on convert(nvarchar(30),tableA.accountNum) = tableB.CisAC 
where tableB.CisAc is null
```

Answer (score 3):

You query is correct. It's returning the expected results.

See here for the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dfb5d/1

What is probably happening is that the data you have in `tableB` is not matching the data in `tableA`.

Edit:

As @Andomar answered, if `tableB` has a null value, the query will fail. See here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05bb1/1